# Set strategy.exit Limit to close when price reaches EMA

Tags: pine-script

I want my strategy to close whenever 4H price **reaches** 12 EMA but somehow it closes way above and I don't think it's possible for EMA to reach the price at which trade is getting closed.

Relevant code is quite simple:

```
fastMA = ta.ema(close, 12)

if strategy.position_size != 0 
    strategy.exit("profit", from_entry="EL", limit = fastMA, stop = high)
```

And this is my result on 4H chart:

[image]

Green line is the 12 EMA configured as follows:

[image]

**Do you have any hints what might be wrong or where my assumptions are incorrect?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stop loss is getting triggered.

You set it `stop=high` which means it will set your stop loss at previous bar's `high' price.

You can use the `comment_profit` and `comment_loss` arguments of the `strategy.exit` to see which exit type was executed.

Comment: You're right, thank you very much! also appreciate tips regarding `comment_` arguments